# Deployment of Next.js 13 App on AWS with MongoDB, Google Places API, and API Routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, deployment, next.js13

### Overview

I'm relatively new to web development, and I apologize if my questions seem basic or inexperienced.

I have developed a Next.js 13 application(locally) that contains a big React form page. This form collects user data and presents the results on a separate page. The app utilizes API routes located in the `app/api` directory. These API routes include autocompletion functionality with MongoDB and the Google Places API. Additionally, there is a result calculation route that retrieves data from the database and do some mathematics to generate the result page.

### Goal

I am seeking guidance on deploying this Next.js 13 application on AWS and ensuring the proper setup and integration of MongoDB, Google Places API, and the API routes during the deployment process.

### Specific Questions

1. **AWS Lambda**: Should I put all the api route logic into a lambda fuction inorder to deploy it on aws
2. **AWS Deployment**: What are the recommended steps for deploying a Next.js 13 app on AWS? Are there any AWS services that are particularly well-suited for this type of application?
3. **MongoDB Integration**: How can I seamlessly integrate MongoDB into my AWS-deployed Next.js app? Are there any best practices or considerations for handling database connections in a production environment?
4. **MongoDb autocompletion and Google Places API**: What steps do I need to take to ensure the continued functionality of the Google Places API in the deployed environment?
5. **API Routes Configuration**: Are there any specific configurations or adjustments needed for the API routes in the `app/api` directory to work effectively in an AWS environment?

I appreciate any insights, recommendations, or step-by-step instructions that can help me successfully deploy and maintain my Next.js 13 app on AWS.

Thank you!